# foreach $data didn't show anything CI Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm working with foreach to display my detail data. last night the details is showed. And when I edited another code for another function (not this details function), and I tried again details function it didn't displayed anything, just blank.
I don't know whats wrong because nothing message error showed up.

*Here's my controller for details function*

```
function getDetail($no_form){
    $data['detail'] = $this->m_read->getDetail($no_form)->result();
    $this->load->view('haha', $data);
}
```

*and my model for details function*

```
public function getDetail($no_form) {
    $this->db->select('input_pen.no_form, input_pen.no_obs, input_pen.catatan, input_pen.tgl_kun,
                        peneliti.inisial,
                        bps.kode_bps,
                        kontak.no_kon, kontak.jabatan, kontak.nama, kontak.telp,
                        lokasi.no_lok, lokasi.kabu, lokasi.keca, lokasi.desa, lokasi.desk, lokasi.utm_y, lokasi.utm_x,
                        tanam.no_tanam, tanam.t_utama, tanam.pola1, tanam.pola2, tanam.pola3, tanam.dlm_olah, tanam.t_tanah,
                        lahan.no_lahan, lahan.jenis, lahan.penggunaan, lahan.kondisi, lahan.drainase,
                        produktivitas.no_prod, produktivitas.p_padi, produktivitas.p_jagung, produktivitas.p_kedelai, produktivitas.pr_lain, produktivitas.prod_lain, produktivitas.pr_lain2, produktivitas.prod_lain2,
                        varietas.no_var, varietas.v_padi, varietas.v_jagung, varietas.v_kedelai, varietas.v_lain, varietas.var_lain, varietas.v_lain2, varietas.var_lain2,
                        pem_padi.np_padi, pem_padi.p_organik, pem_padi.p_urea, pem_padi.p_kcl, pem_padi.p_sp36, pem_padi.p_phonska, pem_padi.p_lain, pem_padi.pp_lain,
                        pem_jagung.np_jagung, pem_jagung.j_organik, pem_jagung.j_urea, pem_jagung.j_kcl, pem_jagung.j_sp36, pem_jagung.j_phonska, pem_jagung.j_lain, pem_jagung.pj_lain,
                        pem_kedelai.np_kedelai, pem_kedelai.k_organik, pem_kedelai.k_urea, pem_kedelai.k_kcl, pem_kedelai.k_sp36, pem_kedelai.k_phonska, pem_kedelai.k_lain, pem_kedelai.pk_lain,
                        pem_lain.np_lain, pem_lain.jenis_l, pem_lain.organik, pem_lain.urea, pem_lain.kcl, pem_lain.sp36, pem_lain.phonska, pem_lain.pupuk_lain, pem_lain.pem_lain');

    $this->db->from('input_pen');
    $this->db->from('bps');
    $this->db->join('peneliti', 'input_pen.no_obs = peneliti.no_obs');
    $this->db->join('kontak', 'input_pen.no_kon = kontak.no_kon');
    $this->db->join('lokasi', 'input_pen.no_lok = lokasi.no_lok');
    $this->db->join('tanam', 'input_pen.no_tanam = tanam.no_tanam');
    $this->db->join('lahan', 'input_pen.no_lahan = lahan.no_lahan');
    $this->db->join('produktivitas', 'input_pen.no_prod = produktivitas.no_prod');
    $this->db->join('varietas', 'input_pen.no_var = varietas.no_var');
    $this->db->join('pem_padi', 'input_pen.np_padi = pem_padi.np_padi');
    $this->db->join('pem_jagung', 'input_pen.np_jagung = pem_jagung.np_jagung');
    $this->db->join('pem_kedelai', 'input_pen.np_kedelai = pem_kedelai.np_kedelai');
    $this->db->join('pem_lain', 'input_pen.np_lain = pem_lain.np_lain');
    $this->db->where('input_pen.no_form', $no_form);
    $this->db->where('bps.kab = lokasi.kabu');
    $this->db->where('bps.kec = lokasi.keca');
    $this->db->where('bps.desa = lokasi.desa');
    $q = $this->db->get();

    return $q;
}
```

*and my view*

```
<div class="row">
     <?php 
         foreach($detail as $d){ 
     ?>
     <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                <h4><label><p class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical"></p> KONTAK</label></h4>
                                <table>
                                <tr>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="nokon" hidden="true">
                                    <td width="150"><label>Jabatan</label></td>
                                    <td><label>:</label></td>
                                    <td width="600">&emsp;<?php echo $d->jabatan ?></td>
                                </div>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <td width="150"><label>Nama</label></td>
                                    <td><label>:</label></td>
                                    <td width="600">&emsp;<?php echo $d->nama ?></td>
                                </div>
                                </tr>
```

but another function that using foreach $data is worked fine.
**edited**
I tried to build this function step by step until reach the same code like i wrote above. At some point the array result in var_dump is 0 and I got this error *allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted*. what should I do then?

Comment: `var_dump($data['detail'])` and see what have been returned by the model before sending it to the view.

Comment: it show array(0) {}, it means my model is wrong?

Comment: Try executing the query in Mysql, then update your result here.

Comment: in mysql the result is perfect, like what i expected

Comment: insted of `$this->m_read->getDetail($no_form)->result();` use `$this->m_read->getDetail($no_form)->get_compiled_select();` this return sql query string. then `var_dump($data['detail']); die(); ` . copy sql query and try to run in mysql.(only for debug)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check  your $data['detail']
before loading the view in controller

```
print_r( $data['detail']);
die();
```

And make sure your foreach is closed properly in view.

Comment: yes, keep print_r and die till you not getting the result .

Comment: um i dont understand, what should i do?

Comment: make sure your $no_form variable has some value.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your Edit:

Your Error:

> allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

For that, you need to increase your Memory limit. Go to your `php.ini` file. Edit `memory_limit`.

This May can solve your problem but before that 
Try to using Xdebug to profile your script and find out where all that memory went.

Because if you're caching some serious amounts of data, `memory_limit` is the correct way. 128M is not enough for certain scripts. 512M or 1024M will often be enough, but you have to decide case by case.